# How to cleanly do overlapping action in Blender?

Tags: animation

I've been struggling lately to do overlapping action in Blender without using the
"offset keys" technique. I can easily get overlapping action in Maya with a pendulum rig, but when I follow the same steps in Blender, the curves are extremely awkward and floaty. Easing in and out is seemingly random, and the curves generated are way different than what Maya creates. I was able to get decent results after trying for about an hour to make the curves look like Maya's, but it was agony.

Is there a certain method I need to use to make this painless? Perhaps a certain interpolation method? As I've said before, I'm trying to avoid using the "offset keys" method.

Maya's animation and curves: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf9po.jpg

Blender's animation and curves: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMGuY.jpg

My awkward attempt to fix the curves: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHuz2.jpg

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: HI, welcome. Please use the question editor "add image" tool, as it's permanent storage, and integrated: it shows images in the post, helping others to understand what you mean

Comment: @m.ardito If they haven't correctly added images they likely don't know how to. I generally provide [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) link to explain it to them.